# Are there common implementation strategies for arbitrary-precision arithmetic which are valid regardless of a specific language?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, biginteger

I'm thinking about different ways to implement arbitrary-precision arithmetic (sometimes called Bignum, Integer or BigInt).

It seems like the common idiom is to use an array for the storage of the actual value and reallocate it as needed if space requirements grow or shrink.

More precisely, it seems that the bit size of the array elements is often the second largest size commonly supported (to make calculations with overflow easier to implement probably?), e. g. language/platform supports 128bit-sized numbers -> array of 64bit numbers + 128bit variable to handle overflow.

Are there fundamentally different ways to implement arbitrary-precision arithmetic or is the above the “tried and true” way to implement it without huge performance losses?

My question is about the underlying  data structure, not the algorithms for operations. I know Karatsuba, Toom-Cook et alii.

Comment: For large integers, FFT and DFT are used, I think.

Comment: For efficiency (carry propagation) a bignum is most commonly stored as binary array in little-endian fashion. The size of the array elements indeed has to do with the ability for a computer to process the numbers to get a carry (for additions) or borrow (for subtraction). Programming language specific, the array holding the bignum can be a byte array, since the bytes can be easily cast into the most efficient data type available. 4 bytes to a int, 8 bytes to a long etc.

Comment: Actually, for addition and subtraction, you could use the native bit length. If there is a carry, `a+b < min(a, b)` and `a-b > a` for positive integers. But it is fairly tricky to handle overflow in multiplication. Doable, but best left to the CPU. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to [represent large integers](http://www.dragonwins.com/domains/getteched/crypto/chinese_remainder_theorem.htm) in a fundamentally different way from the usual base-2^n system.

I believe a CRT-based representation will still use an array of elements which, like the conventional representation, are based on the most convenient native arithmetic available.  However, these elements hold the remainders of the number when divided by a sequence of primes, not base-2^n digits.

As with the conventional representation, the number of elements used determines the maximum size of the representable number.  Unfortunately, it is not easy to compute whether one CRT-based number is greater than another, so it is hard to tell if your representation has overflowed the maximum size.  Note that addition and multiplication are very fast in CRT representation, which could be an advantage if you can deal with the overflow issue.

However, to answer your question:  I believe it is accurate to say that the base-2^n system is indeed the "tried and true" representation, which is used by most popular bignum libraries.  I think I recall that there are extant CRT-based bignum libraries, although I have not checked lately to see if they are still around....

Comment: +1, CRT-based representation is the internal representation for some of the Number-Theoretic Transform (NTT) based algorithms for multiplication.