# Examples of Chinese Remainder Theorem being used to represent big numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, biginteger

In Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming*, Chapter 4.3.2 (Vol. 2) is titled "Modular Arithmetic", and its focus is on how we can use modulo arithmetic to represent very large numbers, and then add, subtract and multiply them. If we do this cleverly, the Chinese Remainder Theorem means no information is lost in this process.

However, I'm have trouble finding examples of this use in (recent) practice. I found a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7879312/10021119) which has the tantalizing comment: "CRT-based representation is the internal representation for some of the Number-Theoretic Transform (NTT) based algorithms for multiplication". So my question is therefore:

> Which Number-Theoretic Transform (NTT) based algorithms for multiplication use a CRT-based internal representation?

I'm a mathematician rather than a programmer, so I'm doing this because I am interested rather than because I have a specific application in mind. So any "common" systems which uses this, or anything generally interesting, would be appreciated.

Comment: One example where CRT is used is in [RSA decryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm), where the recipient of a message knows the prime factorisation of the modulus and can therefore compute the decrypted message modulo each of the two primes individually, rather than their product.

Comment: https://tches.iacr.org/index.php/TCHES/article/view/8791